# How Would I Write This Registry Using 'Reg Add'?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The registry I am attempting to write with reg add to be called in bat file is this.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00    

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\RICOH]    

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\RICOH\JOBCODEv2]    

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\RICOH\JOBCODEv2\Gestetner MP C305 PCL 6]
"current_jobcode::\\\\print.servernet\\SomeRoom_RCHC305"=hex:e1,96
"printer_icon_code::\\\\print.servernet\\SomeRoom_RCHC305"="1234"
```

I found a quite a few questions similar in nature on stack, but I was unable to derive how to specifically add the above registry.

Comment: can't you use `reg import yourreg.reg` in your batch file?

Comment: Have you tried `reg add /?` ?

Comment: The problem is that the bat file might run on machines where the .reg file is not accessible.

Comment: not sure about the key value, but writing hex strings worked for me in the form `reg add "HKCU\Software\RICOH\JOBCODEv2\Gestetner MP C305 PCL 6" /V "current_jobcode::\\\\print.servernet\\SomeRoom_RCHC305" /T REG_BINARY /D "e1a99bd3f31f41b80d3253ef86f9b24c7c81c0eebe7b61e9786c278605c2bdf5b8c38f3329d4cc36570fe34db719b0d0ee129861476956d9b4d6936bcbadc64fb8ac46e2581020512c7604e74d2a5ca72fcd5a677881972ecbcfd6486a166b6d32f437a760b8bbbfe1c2feadaf2f3a96" /F`

Comment: Please read the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how this site works!

Comment: Sorry what are you asserting I am overlooking in regards to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\RICOH\JOBCODEv2\Gestetner MP C305 PCL 6" /v "current_jobcode::\\print.servernet\SomeRoom_RCHC305" /t REG_BINARY /d "e13a96" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\RICOH\JOBCODEv2\Gestetner MP C305 PCL 6" /v "printer_icon_code::\\print.servernet\SomeRoom_RCHC305" /t REG_SZ /d "1234" /f
```